# Hall sensor placement Inrunner BLDC

Tags: motor, sensor, brushless-dc-motor

I have an In-runner BLDC motor with 9 windings on the stator and 6 poles on the rotor (3 magnet pairs). I am needing to install Hall sensors (41F) in the motor to reduce cogging as I am installing it in an ebike as a mid drive (attached to the crankset). Anyways, I have a motor controller that is set to run either 60 or 120 degree Hall sensor placement. I am trying to figure out the correct placement (and whether or not there is an advantage to running 60 vs 120 degree sensor placement).

I have reduced my calculations down to simply just placing the hall sensors at 120 degrees apart. Either that or doing 40 degrees separation (for the 60 degree configuration) as this would be easier in terms of wiring. I also have a PCB setup with the hall sensors at 40 degrees apart so this would be easiest to install.

Also, would it matter where on the stator these are placed? (given they are separated at the correct degrees).

I am also wondering if the hall sensors should go between the winding gaps or directly in the middle of the faces (facing the rotor magnets). I was told that for a stator having an odd number of windings, they need to go in the faces. VS even would be between the windings. Is this correct?

I have attached some images below of the stator and rotor along with the different Hall sensor configurations.

I know that this subject has been covered numerous times, but I would just like some clarification before I go spending hours tinkering with this. Also, most of the information I’ve found is for outrunner motors and not sure if the math is different for inrunner (my case).

Thanks all! This is my first post. I’m a mechanical engineer and this electrical stuff can be confusing lol
[image: Stator 9 windings]

[image: Rotor 6 pole]

[image: 120 degree seperation (120 electrical degree orientation)]

[image: 40 degree seperation (60 electrical degree orientation)]